# Anbox setting "negative colors"

Tags: android, settings, anbox

Anbox (Android 7.1) was working great, under ubuntu 20.04.  I did a lot of configuration (but no backup yet).  But when I tried: System(Android)-Settings - Accessibility - NegativeColors, now all windows are just black. Any idea how to revert the change?  Found a lot of setting files in  /var/lib/anbox/data  (This is the apt install, not snap)

Any help will be greatly appreciated.